# Flutter having two SliverPersistentHeader stacked one after another

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have `CustomScrollView` with following structure:

```
CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: true,
                floating: true,
                delegate: AddPageAppBarWidget(
                  plantsCompanion: _plantsCompanion,
                  minExtent: 90.0,
                  maxExtent: 300.0,
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                  _plantsCompanion.name.present
                      ? NameWidget(name: _plantsCompanion.name.value)
                      : NameWidget(name: ''),
                ]),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: ScheduledActivityListWidget(
                   plantId: _plantsCompanion.id.value,
                   scheduledActivities: snapshot.data,
                ),
              ),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: LoggedActivitiesSliverAppBarWidget(
                  title: 'Chronology',
                  minExtend: 100,
                  maxExtend: 150,
                ),
                pinned: true,
                floating: true,
              ),
              SliverFixedExtentList(
                    itemExtent: 50.0,
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: Image.asset(
                            loggedActivities[index].activityType.imagePath,
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                          title: Text(formatter
                              .format(loggedActivities[index].created)),
                        );
                      },
                      childCount: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
          )
```

The issue I have - the second `SliverPersistentHeader` goes beneath the first one, while I would like to have it stacked just after it. If I replace the second `SliverPersistentHeader` with `SliverAppBar`, I can achieve the desired effect, however, `SliverAppBar` takes way too much space, hence I would like to replace it with `SliverPersistentHeader`

Comment: Find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter 3.13 includes a new class called [SliverMainAxisGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverMainAxisGroup-class.html). You can use that to group header list pairs.

Here is a working demo which you can paste on https://dartpad.dev/ and run:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverMainAxisGroup(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                child: Container(
                  color: const Color(0xFFFDCE94),
                  child: const Text('Title 1',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF12141D), fontSize: 24)),
                ),
                minHeight: 90.0,
                maxHeight: 300.0,
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                ...List.generate(15, (index) => Text('List 1 Item$index')),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SliverMainAxisGroup(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                child: Container(
                  color: const Color(0xFF4BC9DF),
                  child: const Text('Title 2',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF12141D), fontSize: 24)),
                ),
                minHeight: 100.0,
                maxHeight: 150.0,
              ),
            ),
            SliverFixedExtentList(
              itemExtent: 50.0,
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('List 2 Item$index'));
                },
                childCount: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate({
    required this.minHeight,
    required this.maxHeight,
    required this.child,
  });

  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => max(maxHeight, minHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}
```

Technically they are not stacked together. As you can see Title 2 pushes Title 1 upwards. But obviously better than the previous version.

I hope this helps future readers.